# How to use Async methods of in a queryable generic repository?

Tags: c#, task, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, .net-4.5

In my OData controller, I am using the generic repository found [here](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/) and can do the following:

```
[Queryable]
public Task<IQueryable<ContentType>> Get()
{
    var result = _repository.Query().GetAsync();

    return result;
}
```

As I would like to add some conditions to the query, such as `UserId` and use the `UnitOfWork` pattern,

I'm trying the following:

```
[Queryable]
public Task<IQueryable<ContentType>> Get()
{
    // mock
    var userId = 111;

    var unitOfWork = new Repository.UnitOfWork(_db);

    var result = unitOfWork.Repository<ContentType>().Query().Get()
        .Where(u => u.UserId == userId).Cast<ContentType>() // <-- how to access .GetAsync()

    return result;
}
```

I have tried the following (which works), but wondering if this is in fact the best way of accomplishing this?

```
[Queryable]
public async Task<IQueryable<ContentType>> Get()
{
    // mock
    var userId = 102;

    var unitOfWork = new Repository.UnitOfWork(_db);

    var result = unitOfWork.Repository<ContentType>().Query().Get()
        .Where(u => u.UserId == userId).Cast<ContentType>().AsQueryable();

    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => result);
}
```

**-- Update --**

Based on the discussion, I have removed the async portion of this and done the following:

```
   public IEnumerable<ContentType> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ContentType> options)
    {
        var unitOfWork = new Repository.UnitOfWork(_db);

        // mock
        var userId = 102;

        var contentTypes = options.ApplyTo(unitOfWork.Repository<ContentType>().Query().Get()
            .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
            .OrderBy(c => c.Description))
            .Cast<ContentType>().ToList();

        return contentTypes;
    }
```

I'm not stuck on doing this async, and it doesn't seem like there is a direct way to `.GetAsync()` from `IQueryable<TEntity>` (as defined in IReqpositoryQuery.cs), but curious to know of a proper way of accomplishing this.

Comment: You should not use `Task.Factory.StartNew` (or `Task.Run`) in ASP.NET. For your other questions, they're probably best asked [here](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/discussions).

Comment: @StephenCleary - Thanks.  Do you have an alternate suggestion for this?

Comment: If you don't have naturally-asynchronous methods (i.e., provided by the Generic Repository library), then you should just use the synchronous methods. On ASP.NET, you should not use "fake asynchronous" techniques such as offloading work to another thread.

Comment: @StephenCleary Of course, in this specific case there *are* ways of doing what he wants using proper asynchrony, looking through the API he's using, so he *doesn't* need to do the work synchronously.

Comment: @Servy - Right, I don't need to do the work asynch - not a requirement, just wanted to follow the pattern set forth by the OData controller template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Filter` method of `IRepositoryQuery` rather than using `Where`:

```
[Queryable]
public Task<IQueryable<ContentType>> Get()
{
    // mock
    var userId = 111;

    var unitOfWork = new Repository.UnitOfWork(_db);

    return unitOfWork.Repository<ContentType>().Query()
        .Filter(u => u.UserId == userId)
        .GetAsync();
}
```